# Can I read Google Sheet as CSV file

Tags: go

Using Go language, is there a way that I can read the date saved at GoolgeSheets as CSV file, without downloading offline copy of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, with the below steps:

1. In Googlesheets:

- Publish the sheet under consideration as csv file, using File -> Publish to the web, make sure to select the option "Automatically republish when changes are made"
- Copy the link provided by googleSheets for the csv connectivity

[image]

2. In Go lang

- Use the below code:

```golang
// file main.go
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func readCSVFromURL(url string) ([][]string, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    reader := csv.NewReader(resp.Body)
    reader.Comma = ','
    data, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return data, nil
}

func main() {
    url := "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxxsingle=true&output=csv"
    data, err := readCSVFromURL(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for idx, row := range data {
        // skip header
        if idx == 0 {
            continue
        }

        if idx == 6 {
            break
        }

        fmt.Println(row[2])
    }
}
```